# Where do I put perror("wait") with fork code

Tags: c, fork

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv) {


    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if(pid == 0) {
            while(1) {
                pid_t pid2 = fork();
                wait(NULL);

            }
        }

    }
    wait(NULL);
    return(0);

}
```

Basically the program runs several hello world processes and closes with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. How would I do the wait error? Like perror(wait). I think I have to use int status instead of NULL but unsure how to go about it when theres orphan processes involved.

The given code is

```
$ gcc -Wall above.c
$ ./a.out
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
^C (until ctrl C is hit)
$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `perror` is only useful when you know that a function failed and
`errno` is set, so you want to print an error message. You usually write
`perror("something failed")` right after the function that could fail **and**
sets `errno` (the documentation of the function will tell you whether the
function set `errno` on failure).

> *man perror*
>
> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
>    #include <stdio.h>
>
>    void perror(const char *s);
>
>    #include <errno.h>
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The  `perror()`  function produces a message on standard error describing the last error encountered during a call to a system or library
>   function....

This has nothing to do with `wait` and it's parameter, it's only useful if
`wait` fails and you want to print an error message about `wait` failing.

> *man wait*
>
> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
>    #include <sys/types.h>
>    #include <sys/wait.h>
>
>    pid_t wait(int *wstatus);
>
>    pid_t waitpid(pid_t pid, int *wstatus, int options);
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> All  of these system calls are used to wait for state changes in a child of the calling process...
>   ...
>
> `wait()` and `waitpid()`
>
> The  `wait()`  system  call  suspends  execution of the calling process until one of its children terminates.  The call `wait(&wstatus)` is
>   equivalent to:
>
> ```
>        waitpid(-1, &wstatus, 0);
> ```
>
> ...
>
> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> `wait()`: on success, returns the process ID of the terminated child; on error, -1 is returned.
>
> ...
>
> Each of these calls sets `errno` to an appropriate value in the case of an error.

If you just want to wait for a child to exit, you can do just `wait(NULL)`.
However if you want to know the status of the child that exited, then you have
to pass a pointer to `int`.

```
int wstatus;

pid_t wp = wait(&wstatus);

if(wp == -1)
{
    // here I use perror because if wait returns -1 then there
    // was an error and errno is set
    perror("could not wait for child\n");
    exit(1);
}

if(WIFEXITED(wstatus))
    printf("Child with pid %d exited normally with status %d\n", wp, WEXITSTATUS(wstatus));
else
    printf("Child with pid %d exited abnormally\n", wp);
```

I personally prefer `waitpid` over `wait`, it gives you more control over the
child you are waiting.

See [man wait](https://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid)